# How do I write a custom validator for a zend form element with customized error messages?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, zend-validate

I have a question field with a list of allowed characters : A-Z,0-9,colon (:), question mark (?), comma(,), hyphen(-), apostrophe (').
I have the regex which works fine, in the fashion :

```
 $question->addValidator('regex', true, array(<regular expresstion>))
```

The default error message is something like ''' does not match against pattern ''

I want to write a custom error message that says ' is not allowed in this field'

Is there a simple way to do it using the existing zend components that I'm missing?

Is writing a custom validator the only way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve?
If yes, how do I write a custom validator (I looked at the documentation and didn't quite understand how I can customize the error messages) 
If there is any other way, I'd most appreciate that input too.

Thanks for taking the time to answer this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the custom validator fits your needs. On how to write it, please refer to this [manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html).

With regards to a code snippet, here's a simple validator(partial) for validating employer ID

```
protected $_messageTemplates = array(
    self::UNIQUE => 'The id provided is already in use',
    );

public function isValid($value, $context = null)
{
    $this->_setValue($value);

    $personnel = new Personnel();
    $isValid = true;

    if( $personnel->isExistingIdEmployee($value) && ($value != $this->_id) ) {
        $this->_error(self::UNIQUE);
        $isValid = false;
    }

    return $isValid;
}
```